# Hour by hour Timeline display of 'events' - mysql php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have been googling for a while but haven't come up with anything great as yet.

What I want to do is take mysql data (below)
[image: mysql table]

and display it in an hourly timeline, something like:
[image: desired timeline]

Anyone got any good links or tutorials on how to make this happen?

Not looking for an exact solution(although that helps) but just some direction t get me started.

so mysql db with php and jquery

Thanks,

Comment: in mysql `HOUR(InTime)` and `MINUTE(InTime)` will give elements of the datetime column, or `date("HM", strtotime($record['InTime']));`, this converted to seconds, will give you the start x co-ordinate, Add duration in seconds will give the end co-ordinate. Use `imagefilledrectangle();` from the GD library to create the boxes, and `imagefttext();` for the numbers

Comment: Does this have to be continuously updating or only when the page loads?

Comment: @Waygood, I could not read into the question that he wants to draw an image. Should be possible to create a similar look in HTML/CSS, too – getting coordinates the same way you described, and translate them to left/right coordinates for absolute positioning.

Comment: Sorry for slow response. Thanks Waygood, concept is understood. NoLiver92, on page reload is fine and can set the page to reload every 5 minutes or whatever.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These timeline / gantt plugins should get you most of the way there, likely just need to setup the JSON data:

1. [dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) (Timeline View)

   [image: Timeline View]
2. [Bluelinemedia Timeline](http://www.bluelinemedia.co.uk/timelinedemo/)

   [image: Bluelinemedia Timeline]
3. [Pure CSS Timeline - Matt Bango](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/pure-css-timeline/) (link does not work anymore)

   [image: Pure CSS Timeline]
4. [Chronoline JS](http://stoicloofah.github.com/chronoline.js/)

   [image: Chronoline JS]
5. [Timeline JS](http://timeline.verite.co/)

   [image: Timeline JS]
6. [jQuery.Gantt](http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/)

   [image]

Most of these found using **timeline**, **gantt**, **jQuery**, **js** keywords

Comment: All these products look like good solutions, but I think the issue is that most products don't handle or display hours/minutes well. Jquery Gantt for instance handles scale of hours but not minutes.  Would be interested in other people's experience.

Answer (score 7):

I have been looking for something that can display a timeline with a higher time resolution as well (at least down to hours and minutes). This Timeline might be able to be handle just that:

[**Timeline** by Jos de Jong and Almende B.V.](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/)

Answer (score 6):

[Timestack](http://isaaccambron.com/timestack/) is also interesting (and easily hackable).

Google [have also](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) their own timeline chart.